# Delete files in batch with without error message

Tags: batch-file, delete-file

I use the command

```
del "info*"
```

to delete a group of files starting with "info". The problem is that sometimes there 
is at least one of these files that exist,therefore they are deleted and others times no files exist and and error message happens. 
I need my script must not block if these files don't exist.

I look at options for del /?  but nothing help me go ahead.

Could you help me, please?

Comment: Are you using `del /q info*.*` ?

Comment: I think the /Q parameter only allow you to skip the confirmation message, it will still output an error "Can't find [...]". Might be wrong though

Comment: @RelevantUsername You're not wrong

Comment: Deleting `node_modules` directory is `DEL /F/Q/S node_modules > NUL 2>&1  &  RMDIR /S/Q node_modules > NUL 2>&1`

Answer (score 49, accepted):

try this:

```
del "file to delete" >nul 2>&1
del "info*" >nul 2>&1
```

This sends normal and error messages to `nul`.

```
del "file to delete" 2>nul
del "info*" 2>nul
```

This sends only error messages to `nul`.

Comment: This method would mask error messages that are not related to the file not existing. For example, access denied.

Answer (score 73):

Did you tried something like this :

```
IF EXIST [Filename] (
    del [Filename]
) ELSE (
    ...
)
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The one that is accepted would mask error messages besides the file not existing.

Comment: @ParakramMajumdar Unfortunately, it does not handle wildcards.

Answer (score 6):

Another way could be this one:

```
for /f "delims=" %a in ('dir /B /S info*') do del "%a"
```

This will do a dir to get a list of suitable files. If any found, do for each a "del ".

Looks a little bit overkill, but will prevent errors like "file info* not found".